# sending sms using Smsmanager in a service for android 4.4 and above

Tags: android

I'm working in a  service which is being shown in foreground where i need to send sms i'm using following code in service class

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, "text", null, null);
```

and i had took following permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" but it's not working no message is being sent

Comment: Did you take runtime permissions or only added it in manifest?

Comment: only in manifest

Comment: how do i add permission in runtime in service class?

Comment: did you try to search "android send sms example". your app should have requested for SMS permission when launched first time. check this link "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm"

Comment: ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() needs activity context but i'm working in service  and if i'm giving "this" it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Declare:

```
public static final int PERMISSION_CODE_SEND_SMS  = 123;
```

Check if permission granted :

```
if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            PERMISSION_CODE_SEND_SMS);

    return;
}
```

Now handle the response:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case  PERMISSION_CODE_SEND_SMS: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted send SMS now

        } else {

            // permission denied ask again
        }
        return;
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: checkSelfPermission()  asking for api level 23 i need it for at least api 19

Comment: Doesn't matter your minimum sdkversion. If your target is above 23 you need to use the above method

Comment: Take these permissions in the main activity

Answer (score 0):

In main activity checked for  permissions

```
   private void checkForSmsPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
    } else {
        // Permission already granted. Enable the SMS button.
       permission=1;
    }
}


        @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    // For the requestCode, check if permission was granted or not.
         switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (permissions[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted. Enable sms button.
                permission = 1;
            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                permission = 0;
                // Disable the sms button.

            }
         }
        }
      }
```

and send permission detail to service class via intent as permission variable(int)

```
       checkForSmsPermission();
       final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Chat.class);
       intent.putExtra("permission",permission);
       ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent);
```

in service class chked permission and sent message(when sent button is hit)

```
                if (permission==1) {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else
                {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
```